# Unity sprite is missing on the display, but is showing in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project sprite is missing on the display, but is showing in the editor.
[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a zero-frame animation for this object?
Possibly a Z-index issue on the sprite renderer?

Comment: @LeiMagnus this object does not have animator component at all. Sprite component and sprite settings are the same as other objects or sprites.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "order in layer" of the sprite renderer (for the foreground sprites) higher?

Comment: @LeiMagnus Wolfs sprite has the same order in layer as players sprite on the sceenshot above, and I also tried to set order a lot higher. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only  solution I found was to create new game object with all the same components and settings. I still do not know the reason of my problem, so lets consider it as Unity bug.

Right now it seems to me that Y coordinate was too little.